# to transform output of JSON based on the no.of names

Tags: jquery, regex, jq

Input is data extracted from card.
Finding it difficult to extract especially because the **0.jpg** is dynamically generated based on the name of image

.doc.0.jpg becomes invalid and so unable to fetch values under 0.jpg

```
"doc": {
    "0.jpg": {
      "cNumber": "6218961 450 3875",
      "cNames": " 1 VEN NUT 2 SIRKA SARTH",
      "cExpiry": "09/2025"
    },
    "number": {
      "nTotal": 3,
      "nRequires": 3,
      "nDocuments": 1
    }
  }
```

I should be able to extract the names based on the number in cNames

Output should be

```
"doc": {
    "0.jpg": {
      "cNumber": "6218961 450 3875",
      "cNames": [ "VEN NUT",
                  "SIRKA SARTH"],
      "cExpiry": "09/2025"
    },
    "number": {
      "nTotal": 3,
      "nRequires": 3,
      "nDocuments": 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: Users aren't notified when you ping them like that in comments – and that's a good thing. You don't need any specific user to help you; if you ask a good question, you'll get answers from many people. This currently is not a good question, though, it seems to just ask for somebody to do the work for you.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes am trying to figure out how jq works still .. and so my questions might seem very silly for experts

Comment: I can see two ways how you can improve your question: drop everything that's unrelated; you really want to know "how can I convert this string into an array in jq, according to the following rules: ...?" and secondly, if you can show what you have tried, what your result was and how it's different from what you want, the question looks more like part of an effort on your part to solve a problem, instead of a work order for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

```
.doc |= map_values(if has("cNames")
                   then .cNames |= [splits(" *[0-9]+ *")][1:]
                   else . end)
```